# how can i install android emulator on Apple Silicon Chip M1?

Tags: android-studio, apple-m1

I cannot run my android emulator anymore with the M1 chip, I've trying a lot of settings but it just doesn't go through

Answer (score 1):

Right now there's not an release for Android Emulator for M1 Chip. But you can test the preview version.

This is the official repo from Google

https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview

And here you can download the pre-release versions:

https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview/releases

Comment: It says right on the repo "Note: No longer needed" :(

Answer (score 1):

Good news !

> Apple Silicon Support

There is an **arm64** release version available for **Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1)**
You can download it here https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

<s>NDK with `Unknown host CPU architecture: arm64` doesn't work</s>

Solved https://stackoverflow.com/a/69540773/1079990

End of beta ! Thank you